# Как получить значение из любого введенного поля (любой сайт, приложение, софт)

Tags: python, python-3.11

Как получить введенный текст из любого поля ввода с помощью кода на python. Такая функция есть у приложения [Caramba Switcher](https://caramba-switcher.com). А именно: это приложение при двойном нажатии shift переводит текст с английского на русский, пример - вы ввели на определенном сайте/приложении текст/запрос,
например руддщ цщкдв, и Caramba Switcher при нажатии двойного shift удаляет этот текст и вводит hello world. Либо то же самое может произойти с выделенным текстом. Как мне получать введенный/выделенный текст с помощью python?

Comment: Если речь идет про сайты и про софт то у них абсолютно по-разному организуется доступ к полю, но  думаю, для этой задачи не нужно получать значение из введенного поля, достаточно отслеживать ввод клавиатуры, возможно мышь, если фокус поля не теряется, далее просто выделяется все значение (эмуляцией ctrl+a) и заменяется в данном случае переводом (эмуляцией ctrl+v)

Comment: Понял. Но у меня остался еще один вопрос - как получать выделенный текст?

Comment: Выделенный текст получается эмуляцией нажатия ctrl+c  и просмотром буфера обмена